# How do I set a background image for a grouped table view?

Tags: iphone, image, uitableview, background

I've seen some iPhone applications that use a custom image as the background for a grouped UITableView, instead of the standard gray lines.

How is this achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In another project (developed using 2.2.1) I did this by setting my `UITableView'`s background opacity to 0%, and then simply layering a `UIImageView` behind it using Interface Builder. This allowed me to have a fixed background regardless of the table state. You can also set the background of the `UITableView` to be an image instead, but then the background scrolls with the table. (I don't have the code handy at the moment, but I got the tip a while back on the Apple developer forums).

Note that this can cause some performance issues. Apple discourages using transparency whenever possible because the GPUs on the pre-3GS models aren't particularly beefy.

Answer (score 23):

Here's what worked for me (and fairly simple once I figured it out ;)

1)  Add a view in your app delegate and make it a subview of the window:

```
UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:window.frame];

 bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"screenBG.png"]];
 [window addSubview:bgView];
 [bgView release];
```

2)  On each view controller .m file, under ViewDidLoad, set background color of that particular view to transparent (so the other bgView created above will show through):

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

And in my case, the view controller in step 2 was a tableviewcontroller.  Looks great.

And BTW, doing the following in each view controller did NOT work well:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"screenBG.png"]];
```

So follow steps 1 and 2 above.

Hope this helps out,
Tbone

Comment: In the app delegate you can also more easily do: self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];

Comment: I agree with Gil Margolin here... it was WAY easier to set the window's backgroundColor as an image. With one caveat - you have to manually load the correct image for retina/iphone5, which complicated things a bit.

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"wallpaper.png"]];
    self.tableView.opaque = NO;
}
```

Comment: You can also add an image view behind the table view instead of setting a background color, which will allow you to avoid using a pattern image.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `+[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:(UIImage)]` method like so:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem with colorWithPatternImage: is that you need to use "patterned" images, otherwise your image will be tiled randomly

this link has a simple solution, if you want all your views to have the same background

http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2009/03/how-to-add-a-nice-background-image-to-your-grouped-table-view/

Answer (score 2):

```
self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SortByCategory_320x480.png"]];

self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Hope this will help. It won't display hideous translucent background behind the cells especially in case of Grouped UITableView.

Comment: Accessing parentViewController.view is a terrible idea - you don't know what kind of backing it has, and it's a pretty bad violation of encapsulation.  Even if it works now, the next iOS update may totally break your code. Don't do this.