# Grouped login view

Tags: iphone

I am trying to create a login view with user id and password. I want to have them enclosed in a box. I tried group table view but it looked different. I am trying to have view like below. Can any one please guide me.

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a grouped style for a tableview. Set the background color to blue (you can match the color later). Create 2 sections, the first with 2 cells the second with 1 cell. Set the background color of the cells to white. Add the correct UI elements and you're done.

To match the color exactly, there is a great utility called "DigitalColor Meter" located in Applications/Utilities/ that can get the RGB for anything on your screen.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I didnt know changing the background color works. Can you please tell me how to change background of table view to a specific image.

Comment: @din: You can use the `UIColor` method `+(UIColor *)colorWithPatternImage:(UIImage *)image` the make the background color an image.

Comment: colorWithPatternImage changes the background color of the entire view but not the grouped table view I added in side the uiview. Can you tell me how to change for the tableview.

Comment: @din: Yes... see [How do I set a background image for a grouped table view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370849/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-for-a-grouped-table-view)