# Set the UITableView Section border color

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

How does one set the UITableView Section border color? I have tried and cant seem to change it. its default is white, I want to set it to a gray color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white color is because the separator style is set to Single Line Edged. If you change it to Single Line the white lines will disappear. Not sure if that solves your problem but I don't think you change the color without doing a lot more work.

I believe what Apple uses for its contact heading is `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` for section `0`, instead of a cell in the first section. You can still specify a transparent background and the pinstripe will show behind it. The border will not be there as grouped table view section headers do not have borders.

Whether you built your custom cell in Interface Builder or using code, it should be a fairly trivial task to migrate those views from a `UITableViewCell` to a `UIView` for use with `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`.

I don't know if you'll be able to keep the **Details** title for, say, section `1`, unless you make a label containing that word and add it to the section `0` header view manually.

Finally if all the above advise didnt help then [check this link out](http://pessoal.org/blog/2009/02/25/customizing-the-background-border-colors-of-a-uitableview/).

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to single line and set it as needed and it worked. The only weird thing left is that, when I set the tableviews background like this self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Leather.png"]];  I get the background set for the tableview, but it also sets each section in my table with the background too. So there is an overlapping of the same image only behind each section, looks weird when pulling content down. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: For that I think you should set the `backgroundView` property of your table.

Comment: also this might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370849/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-for-a-grouped-table-view