# iOS – Grouped UITableView with tiled background displayed incorrect

Tags: ios, uitableview, background-image

I'm trying to use a tiled background on the `UITableView` by doing: `tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient_squares.png"]];`

But it will not display correctly for each of the sections will display the background tile overlapped the `UITableView` background.

I've tried setting my `UITableViewCell`'s backgroundColor to clear color to no avail.

EDIT: Added screenshot and tile

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try a custom table-cell and draw this image as per your requirement...

Comment: Why custom UITableViewCell? I want to have a tiled background for the UITableView. The UITableViewCells should "hover" over the tiled background and have no background (clear).

Comment: Do you want the background to scroll with the table or stay static?

Comment: I'd like it to stay static. But also would be interesting to see how it would look when scrolling with the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post did the trick for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5480535/294661

Setting the backgroundColor property of each view in UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

If you have full size background image (not a patterned image), following code can solve your problem.

```
[[self tableView] setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_image.png"]]];
```